# xelatex can't find article.cls, but it exists

Tags: xetex, compiling, article

I have `texlive-latex-base` and `texlive-latex-recommended` installed in my Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to compile this document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{ article }
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

with xelatex, so I type:

```
$ xelatex test.tex test.pdf
```

but it throws this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File ` article .cls' not found.
```

However, I can find `article.cls` in the correct folder `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/`, so I have no idea what's goinf wrong.

It throws a couple more errors like `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` and `! LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined: there is probably something wrong with the class file.`, however it generates a pdf file with a Hello world! printed in.

Why is xelatex not finding the article class? I have surfed these forums but couldn't find any solution.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! TeX is sensitive to spaces, so it should be `{article}`, not `{ article }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, triming the whitespace before and after `article` can eliminate the errors and compile successfully. Just replace

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{ article }
```

with

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to vote you (and the previous commenter) and accept your answer but I need 15 reputation for that, so I will be glad if somebody with more reputation could do that for me.

Comment: @XiruxNefer You can accept the answer by clicking on the greyed out checkmark by the vote counter. Nobody can accept the answer but you. (However, you cannot up-vote it without more reputation - you are right about that.)

Comment: Note that this answer is essentially egreg's comment, which was posted 10 minutes earlier. It would have been more appropriate to suggest that egreg turn that comment into an answer rather than posting those instructions as an answer yourself.

Comment: Just for the record, I am not Justin Yang.